# Mirroring configuartion issue

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

> The server network address TCP://XXXX(Server Name):5023 can not be
>   reached or does not exist. Check the network address name and that the
>   ports for the local and remote endpoints are operational. (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)

II am getting the above Error while doing mirror configuration.

Below are the steps I did for the Mirroring configuration.

- Restored the fullback up to with no recovery option on secondary
  server.
- I tried restoring the Log backup (Error: RESTORE LOG is terminating
  abnormally), hence I skipped the log restore.
- I tired configuring the mirroring and got the success message for
  mirroring configuration but when I start the mirroring my primary
  database shows Primary/Synchronized where as my secondary server
  shows in Recovery.
- When I check the Sql ports in configuration manager it shows 1433 and
  if I check tcp_endpoints it shows 5023.

Can you please help me to fix the Mirroring configuration.

I have tried Creating ENDPOINTS as-well and while creating PARTNER from Server A to B it is success  but when i create partner from B to A it fails. I used below command:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName
SET PARTNER ='TCP://XXX(Ip address):5023'
```